# Java Garbage Collector time limit

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

### Situation

I am developing a client for a contest in Java, and whenever I receive a request, I have two seconds to respond. The time after the response until the next request is unknown.

Sometimes, finding the right response takes nearly 2 seconds, and sometimes it's only a matter of a few milliseconds. The issue is when garbage collection happens in one of the longer calculations (which also allocates a lot of objects) right towards the end of the two seconds, and thus the response is sent too late and I get disqualified.

Using verbose gc output I identified that the gc usually takes about 0.6s, even though I tried to limit it lower. I also tried to invoke `System.gc()` on the shorter calculations (since I am sure I have about 1.8s where I don't need to do anything), but it took 1-3s, which is not safe either.

My program has very few long-living objects, most live shorter than a second.

### Specs

I know that the program will always run on the same machine with these resources available:

- 64 bit Ubuntu
- openjdk:8u151-jre
- one core of an [Intel® Xeon® Prozessor E5-2620 v4](https://ark.intel.com/products/92986/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2620-v4-20M-Cache-2_10-GHz)
- 1.5 GB of RAM

My current jvm parameters:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 \
  -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 \
  -XX:GCPauseIntervalMillis=2050 \
  -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled \
  -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 \
  -XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark \
  -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
```

### Ideas

- Can I somehow tell the gc that it should collect some garbage now, but only for about 1.5 seconds?
- Is there a `System.gc()` equivalent that only works with the young objects and doesn't check the tenured generation?
- Can the jvm parameters be optimised to achieve better results?

Comment: As far as I know you can't really limit the garbage collection. You can only try to hold references to all your variables for the time of calculation as then the GC will definitely not run (as everything is still referenced and therefore can't be freed). Then after the calculation you unreference everything so the gc can run (and drop a System.gc() to hope your Garbage Collection gets the hint)

Comment: Instead of trying to optimize Java garbage collection (which is similar to saying you want to put make up on Godzilla), you might want to try to focus on the bigger issue. Why is it that whenever you receive a request, Java needs to perform a GC? GC does happen a lot but if you find a pattern then it is your program that is causing it to happen. You might want to take a good look at the reason behind it.

Comment: Have you tried using G1 garbage collection, it has more frequent micro cycles that are almost unnoticeable.  System.gc() is simply a suggestion and in modern collectors doesn't do anything obvious.  Replace all your GC params above with:  --XX:+UseG1GC

Comment: A bad approach is to call GC and my friend have the same issue about a bad managment of objects and calling GC or GC doing a lot of work. So he make to run the GC every hout with this parameter: `- java -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000` But I think is a bad approach too. Take a look of your program or read this [GC approach](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3681/6n5srlhqf/index.html)

Comment: time to learn c++

Comment: @AlexC - On the contrary, in a modern JVM (like Java 8) calling `System.gc()` will trigger a GC ... **unless**  it is disabled using `-XX:+DisableExplicitGC`.

Comment: As @AlexC said, you should try G1 collector. I’m not even sure whether CMS supports the `MaxGCPauseMillis` option at all.

Comment: @Stephen C  - Calling System.gc() is still only a suggestion and not a guarantee; the JVM will try to cleanup but can choose not to.  I did a test not long ago where I called System.gc() many times in some cases with no or small delay and the GC logs showed far less actual GC excutions than the calls I made, showing that it's not a guarantee.  This was iwth G1 collector, maybe earlier ones it was guaranteed.

Comment: You said "and in modern collectors doesn't do anything obvious".  That's incorrect.  In most modern JVMs, it triggers a GC *by default*.  That's pretty obvious.   Granted, if the GC is already running triggering it again has no effect.  But there are obvious reasons for that too ....

Comment: *"Calling System.gc() is still only a suggestion and not a guarantee"* people read that somewhere and then repeat it everywhere apparently without understanding it. It is not guaranteed *by the API* to do anything specific. But with additional knowledge of JVM and flags used one can reliably reason about whether it will do something or not. Assuming default configuration on current hotspot it will. Contextual information matters. API guarantees are for portability. Implementation-specific behavior is relevant when diagnosing a specific instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of experimenting, I found the flags I needed and want to share this knowledge now:

- `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` - after comparing log results of G1 and CMS for my usecase I determined t CMS pause times are lower, additionally it still supports single-threaded collections
- `-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent` Upon calling System.gc() not a Full GC will be invoked, but a standard one.
- `-XX:NewRatio=1` the size ratio of old generation to young generation, this is the lowest value since I have very few long-living objects
- `-mx800m` `-ms800m` reduces and fixes the memory size, thus collections will occur more frequent and take less time. Trades throughput for responsiveness.
- `-XX:-UseParNewGC` Disables parallelization for collecting the young generation. This was the dealbreaker and reduced the GC stop-the-world times from 0.2-0.5s to 0.02-0.2s, since i only have one core available. (Combining this with CMS is deprecated and subject to be removed in newer Java versions)

Using these parameters I could reduce GC pause times from varying between 0.4s and 3s down to consistently less than 0.2 seconds. And for completeness, these flags were the most useful for debugging:

```
-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
```

Please don't forget that these are optimised for very specific requirements: Onle one core available, a lot of young garbage, no old collections, very low stop-the-world-pauses

This is a little cheat sheet I can recommend for further reading: http://blog.ragozin.info/2016/10/hotspot-jvm-garbage-collection-options.html

Answer (score 2):

Here are things that you could try to reduce pauses:

- Try the G1 collector instead of CMS
- Use more realistic GC goals.  The current goals allow 200ms of stop-the-world GC time every 2 seconds.  Increase MaxGCPauseMillis and/or reduce GCPauseIntervalMillis.
- Add another core so that the JVM is able to GC in parallel with your application.
- Reduce CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction so that the GC triggers the background GC threads when the heap is less full.
- Reduce the rate at which your application generates garbage.
- Tune your application algorithms so that there is more free time for background GC (on your single core).

Comment: "Add another core" the contest system is not under my control. "Reduce the rate at which your application generates garbage." I have to constantly clone objects for a BFS, so that's not an option either. I thought G1 was optimised for a little more performant environments, but it looks good so far. The only thing I'm wondering is why it logs absolutely no activity, despite the fact that I left `-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps` in there.

Comment: *"I have to constantly clone objects for a BFS, so that's not an option either."* - A Breadth First Search should not require any cloning.  Now it is possible that your "constant cloning" is a convenient way to do .... something .... but you most likely *could* avoid it if you redesigned / recoded your algorithms.  It is an option, though maybe not an attractive one.  (It depends on how much you want to win the competition :-) )

Comment: another question: The two modern GCs always seem to work with multiple workers, which doesn't sound efficient considering I only have one core. So I want my GC to be _concurrent_, but not _parallel_, is that possible?

Comment: Basically, no.  The JVM is multi-threaded, and the GC uses threads to run the GC workers.  If you don't have multiple cores, then the threads will be time-sliced by the OS.